# TypeError: google.map is undefined (even when MapsAPILoader loaded)

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I want to use google.map.XXX (e.g. google.map.LatLng) in my code.

First, to be able to build a project I added `declare let google : any;` before my class definition.

When I tried to run a project, `TypeError: google.map is undefined` error has occured.
I used google.map.XXX in `ngOnInit()` method, therefore i thought "Perhaps GoogleMaps still isn't loaded?"...  So, it was kind of right assumption.

Then I tried to use google.map.XXX inside of code like below

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
    // code that uses namespace of google.map
  });
}
```

and error below has occured:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: google.map is undefined

Why even after MapsAPILoader fired the callback, google.map is undefined?

Comment: did you by any chance miss the s in google.maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is stupid misspell!

❌　google.map.XXX
⭕️　google.maps.XXX

Answer (score 0):

External non-typescript libraries are always tricky and implementing them into the correct scope is just so.

There are multiple options on how you could go about this.

1. Using a prebuilt library such as [AGM](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/) which handles pretty much everything
2. Implement it yourself

   - Load the Script in your html `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR-KEY]" async defer></script>`
   - Import it with `declare let google : any;` just like you did
   - Call the maps functions using `new google.maps.function()` inside the `ngOnInit(){}` environment